Flutter Error Invalid argument(s): Input data length must be a multiple of cipher's block size when decrypting from encryption in PHP
I have an error when trying to decrypt in dart language. with message:

Invalid argument(s): Input data length must be a multiple of cipher's
block size

Here is sample PHP code
function encryptDomainWithToken($domain, $token)
{
    // Encryption method using OpenSSL with AES-256-CBC
    $method = 'AES-256-CBC';
    $ivLength = openssl_cipher_iv_length($method); // IV length
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivLength); // Initialization Vector
    $key = hash('sha256', $token, true); // Derive encryption key from token

    // Data to encrypt
    $data = $domain;

    // Encrypt data
    $encryptedData = openssl_encrypt($data, $method, $key, 0, $iv);

    // Combine IV with encrypted data and encode in base64
    return base64_encode($iv . $encryptedData);
}


Here is dart code
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';
import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart';

String decryptDomainWithToken(String encrypted, String token) {
  final method = AESMode.cbc;

  // Derive key from token using SHA-256
  final key = sha256.convert(utf8.encode(token)).bytes;

  final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(Key(Uint8List.fromList(key)), mode: method));

  // Decode the base64 encrypted string
  final decodedData = base64.decode(encrypted);

  // Determine IV length for AES-256-CBC
  final ivLength = 16;
  final iv = IV(Uint8List.fromList(decodedData.sublist(0, ivLength)));

  final encryptedData = Encrypted(Uint8List.fromList(decodedData.sublist(ivLength)));

  // Decrypt the data
  return  encrypter.decrypt(encryptedData, iv: iv);
  
}

How to fix it?

$encryptedData is Base64 encoded (default encoding of openssl_encrypt() for $options = 0). In the Dart code the Base64 decoding (of decodedData.sublist(ivLength)) is missing (note that the library exposes Encrypted.fromBase64()).

so which part should i change?

You can fix this on both sides. The most convenient (and efficient) way is probably to pass OPENSSL_RAW_DATA as the 4th parameter on the PHP side in openssl_encrypt(), which avoids the double Base64 encoding.

how to fix in dart side?

Is already described in my first comment.

it solved whenpass OPENSSL_RAW_DATA as the 4th parameter on the PHP side in openssl_encrypt(). Thank you so much!
